# Calcular fecha usando algoritmo Easter en aplicación Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando hacer con Vue.js una app que al introducir un año utilice un algoritmo que produce como salida el Easter (o domingo de resurreción de Semana Santa) . El algoritmo de esta web que uso lo he estado comprobando con la salida que da en otras páginas en las que vienen tablas con dichas fechas y coinciden, lo que no me coincide es cuando lo aplico en mi app de Vue, no sé si porque lo implemento mal (aunque lo aplico como en la web de donde he sacado el algoritmo), o porque de la forma que lo uso es no es correcta en Vue o javascript, pero se me desvian las fechas en días.

El algoritmo está sacado de esta web (la encontré en un post aquí en Stack)
https://www.irt.org/articles/js052/index.htm

El código principal está en el archivo output.html, que son las funciones que tengo en mi archivo easter.js.

y éste es el código que tengo en mi index.html. La forma (y creo que las que usan) en la que llamo a las funciones en mi computed property creo que es similar a como calculan ahí el Easter Sunday.

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Elige festividad</h1>
<form class="form-inline">
  <input v-model="a"  class="form-control">
  <select v-model="operator" class="form-control">
    <option>SemanaSanta</option>
    <option>SaJ</option>
  </select>
</form>
<h2>Result: {{a}} = {{c}}</h2>

...

<script src="easter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
  a: 0,
  operator: "SemanaSanta",
},
computed: {
   c: function () {
     switch (this.operator) {
       case 'SemanaSanta':
         var easter = Easter(this.a)
         var eDay = getDD(easter)
         var eMonth = getMM(easter)
         return FullDate(eDay,eMonth,this.a);
       case 'SaJ':
         return this.a
     }
   }
 },
});
```

Se agradece cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Podras decir que es lo que no coincide? que entra en esa funcion, que esperas que salga y que recibis?

Comment: no me coincide la fecha de salida, por ejemplo tiene que ser Sunday 21 de Abril y a mi me sale Monday 22 de Abril, otros años si que me coinciden, pero cuando es bisiesto, como este ejemplo que he puesto, no. Años más posteriores, en algunos se me desvía bastante la fecha. En la función entra el año (2019, 2020, etc) y como salida debería ser el formato de salida de la función FullDate(day, month, year).

Comment: Salida: Result: 2020 = Monday 13th April 2020 ,  Result: 2022 = Saturday 23rd April 2022

Comment: y donde estas comprobando los resultados correctos?

Comment: @gbianchi, estoy comprobando las salidas de una año introducido en esta web https://www.irt.org/articles/js052/frame.htm con la salida de mi app, y después he comprobado que las salidas de los años introducidos en esa web conciden con esta otra https://capillitasmontillanos.blogspot.com/p/calendario-de-fiestas-moviles-hasta-el.html

Comment: ok. La variable computada parece ok. habras copiado algo mal del algoritmo? no parece haber ningun problema de vue

Comment: @gbianchi, en mi archivo easter.js tengo todas las funciones con las que calculan las fechas en esa web, (el archivo output.html) pero debe haber alguna cosa al obtener la fecha en la entrada o lo que sea que no lo logro encontrar, pero por ejemplo en la salida que he puesto del año 2022 hay un desfase de 6 días (a mi me sale el sabado 23 de abril del 2022) y la fecha correcta es Domingo 17 de abril de 2022). No me añade el desfase de días de un año a otro o algo similar.

Comment: puede ser un problema de redondeo... suena a eso.. pero sin ver las funciones que estas usando o algun ejemplo va a ser dificil ayudarte

Comment: @gbianchi, todas las funciones que uso (y que hay) están aquí https://www.irt.org/articles/js052/source.htm#output. Yo las tengo en mi archivo easter.js y las que uso en index.html ya ves que son las que están mi computed property. (Easter(), getDD() y getMM()) que a su vez usan otras. Tiene bastante chicha este algoritmo. Gracias de todas formas.